# Memory usage graph for Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to trace a memory leakage on my Windows Server 2008. There are different schedule tasks run by the web app which I suspect the leakage is happening so I want to know at which particular time of the day when the mem usage hikes.

Is there a tool which I can use to track only that particular process?

Website is running on ASP.NET with IIS 7.

Answer (score 2):

Every windows server since NT comes with [Performance Logs and Alerts](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749154.aspx). It can be accessed with the "perfmon" mmc tool. You can add counter logs for overall memory or memory of a process at various intervals then review the logs at a later date. Perfmon allows you to instrument just about any counter windows tracks.

It looks like the interface has changed slightly in 2008 but here's a simple guide for [monitoring memory of a JVM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-memusage/#N10166) from ibm. The basic concepts of counters/logs should remain the same.

For a simple tool to be able to view current status (and brief history) of a system try [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/sysinternals/bb896653)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the most straightforward approach would be to install DebugDiag 1.2, and enable the LeakTrack functionality.

After launching DebugDiag, select the Processes tab, right-click the desired w3wp.exe process, and select "Monitor for leaks".

You may use the Rules tab to create a trigger to collect the information:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

After the user dump files have been generated, you can then use the Advanced Analysis tab, and run the Memory Pressure Analyzer, which will inspect the dump files and generate a report.

From the documentation:

"The memory leak monitoring feature is designed to track memory allocations for a process.  This feature should be used when a process on the system continues to grow in memory until the system becomes unstable, or the process stops functioning correctly.  The debug tool will inject a DLL into the specified process and monitor memory allocations over time.  A dump is then generated, and the dump is analyzed to determine what allocations are not being freed and most likely causing the memory leak.  Allocations generally fall into 3 groups:  caching, short term allocations that will be freed later, and memory leaks.  All three allocation methods have very distinct allocation patterns when measured over time.  The leak tracking feature calculates a leak probability using a formula that is based on these allocation patterns as measured over a specific time period. "

**Debug Diagnostic Tool v1.2**
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26798